# Embedded Tomcat fails to start due to UnrecoverableKeyException

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, ssl, keystore

My embedded tomcat server fails to start due to some problem related to the keystore.

I've found lots of posts related to this issue in stackoverflow and similar platforms. Most of the suggested solutions imply key and keystore password mismatch. That's not the case. The passwords are the same.

My server is built on base of jhipster and it starts successfully with another keystore issued for our organisation.

```
spring boot version: 1.3.3.RELEASE
spring batch version: 2.2.0.RELEASE
spring beans version: 4.2.5.RELEASE
tomcat embed version: 8.0.32
jre version: 1.8.0_171-b11
```

I've built a simple [project](https://github.com/zeevbensender/tomcat-with-ssl.git) based on embedded tomcat, that contains nothing but a single rest controller. This simple server starts successfully with the 
same keystore that causes my server to fail.

The stacktrace is very similar to most posts related to the keystore issue:

```
[ERROR] 2018-ÎíÎñÎÿ-06 09:46:33 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-443"]
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
        at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineGetKey(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(Unknown Source)
        at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:619)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:548)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:360)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:473)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:151)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at com.merc.autop.uhub.Application.main(Application.java:99)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] 2018-ÎíÎñÎÿ-06 09:46:33 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService - Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:151)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at com.merc.autop.uhub.Application.main(Application.java:99)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
        at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineGetKey(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(Unknown Source)
        at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:619)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:548)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:360)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:473)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986)
        ... 18 common frames omitted
[WARN] 2018-ÎíÎñÎÿ-06 09:46:33 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase - The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Hikari Housekeeping Timer (pool HikariPool-0)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[WARN] 2018-ÎíÎñÎÿ-06 09:46:33 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase - The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] 2018-ÎíÎñÎÿ-06 09:46:33 org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:165)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at com.merc.autop.uhub.Application.main(Application.java:99)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:159)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:62)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:165)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at com.merc.autop.uhub.Application.main(Application.java:99)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:159)
        ... 14 more
```

Comment: Maybe the Java version should be there too. Have you used the SAME Java version on your server and when you have tested it locally? If not, please try to use the same. If yes, compare the java.security of the two installation, maybe the provider list differs or there is some other diff. If you have your keystore contents (keys, certs, etc.) you can try to generate a new one. Btw how that keysore have been created? Are you able to check its content for example with [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/open-keystore.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I use the same java version in both cases. I'll add the Java version to the question